# C# CefSharp Snapshot Problems

Tags: c#, snapshot, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

My goal is to develop a bot and I want it to make DrawToBitmap from the Cef browser in the background. But this method does not work in CefSharp.

So I tried the code below;
**https://gist.github.com/jankurianski/f3419d4580517516c24b**

But it didn't work. Then I tried the following command in mainform, but again I could not get a return.

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "");
```

When the form screen is minimized, I can also take a screenshot and convert it to bitmap.

**I want to get snapshots in any case.**

(Btw. sorry for my english :/ )

Comment: You can use the CefSharp.Offscreen package for taking screen shots. The way you are attempting is unsupported.

Comment: How do I use the CefSharp.Offscreen package?

Comment: There is an example at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample There is a more complex example in the main project source

Comment: its not working

Comment: Please ask an actual question.